# Why won't sage math evaluate this expression?

Tags: sage

```
var('u_5 u beta')
y = u - u_5 + beta*(exp(u)-u-4)
beta = 1.0
u_5 = -4.0
p = y.subs(u==u_5)
p
```

results in: 0.0183156388887342*beta - u_5 - 4.00000000000000

How can I get a numerical value? I did try numerical_approx, n() etc.

I expect it to multiply 0.0183... by 1 (beta) and subtract the -4 for u_5

Comment: What Language is this?

Comment: It is the sage math software

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not completely clear on what you're trying to do, but how about this:

```
var('u_5 u beta')
y = u - u_5 + beta*(exp(u)-u-4)
p = y.subs(u==u_5)
p.subs(beta==1., u_5=-4.)
```

should return `0.0183156388887342`. More succinctly, you can combine the last two lines:

```
p = y.subs(u==u_5).subs(beta==1., u_5=-4.)
```

(You have to substitute for `u` first and then plug in `u_5`, so I think these have to be done in stages.)

One of the issues with your approach: when you evaluate `beta = 1.0`, this redefines `beta`, but it doesn't substitute this new definition into any existing expressions containing it. The `subs` method does this.

Comment: Okay thanks a lot for the additional details and approaches. I can move the beta = 1 to immediately after the variable declaration.

Comment: If you're doing that, you don't need to define it as a symbolic variable. Just do `var('u u_5')` and `beta=1.0`.